# LED driver does not give constant current with a load

Tags: current-source, led-driver, ohms-law, current-sink

I'm working with an [AL5810Q](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AL5810Q.pdf), which is a linear LED driver where the current can be set with only one external resistor following $$I_{LED}=\frac{750}{R_{SET}}.$$
With that, since I need a current of 10mA I calculated an external resistor of 75kΩ. (Vin = 12V)

I did a simple test following the schematics provided in the datasheet, which are the following
[image]

So far, so good. 10mA Sharp.

However, the application I have in mind considers a very high line impedance (≈100Ω/mm) so I wanted to model that impedance by means of a resistor of 330Ω, which would leave the previous schemes like this:

[image]

by implementing these resistors the current is no longer constant and becomes a ratio to the voltage.

To be honest, I was not expecting this behavior, but it doesn't surprise me. The block diagram is as follows (with resistors)

[image]

can anyone shed some light on what might be happening and what I can do to fix this.

Comment: What's V_in and R? It can only be compliant up to a certain voltage. [Edit] the details into your question.

Answer (score 1):

The minimum voltage drop across the device is 2.5 V. Add in a couple of green LEDs and you've got a minimum voltage drop of 2.5 + 2 × 2.2 = 6.9 V.

If your supply is, say, 12 V then the maximum cable voltage drop is 12 - 6.9 = 5.1 V giving a maximum resistance of *V/I = 5.1/10m = 510* Ω. At 100 Ω/mm that would give you a max of 5 mm of conductor before you're in trouble.

You can recalculate for your supply voltage.

Comment: makes sense to me. However, I have done two independent tests, one with a red led and the other with a white one (both using the same resistor I mentioned above 330 ohms.) which have a voltage drop of 1.8 and 3 respectively, so there should be enough space to not have this behavior?

Comment: Also, what I see from playing with the source is the current makes a curve, peaking at the desired current (10mA) when Vin = 7 to 9 V. Before and after it decreases.

Comment: You haven't supplied the detail requested under your question and the information in the comments above is a bit vague. Tabulate it properly in your question along with details of the series resistance.

Comment: I did but in the question itself. Anyways. R= 330Ohms and Vin = 12V. 
Now I'm making some test with a white LED (OSRAM LW Q38E-Q1OO-3K6L-1) and with an R-value of 200Ohm.  Vin<6.8V, I<10mA. when 6.8<Vin<8.9V, I=10mA and when Vin>8.9, I<10mA.

Answer (score 0):

Any constant current source must have a minimum voltage drop to regulate the feedback and internal drop.   Adding excessive resistance will defeat this requirement.